# Printing hollow diamond : what's wrong with this function that make the middle of diamond missing?

Tags: python

What's wrong with this function that makes the middle of the diamond missing ?

```
def hollow_diamond(n):
    # Upper half of the diamond
    for i in range(n):
        
        if i == 0 or i == n - 1:
            print(" " * ((n-i)+1) + "*" )
        elif i == 1:
            print(" " * ((n-i)+1) + "***" + " " )
        elif i == (n+1):
            print("**" + " " * ((2*i+1) - 2) + "**" )
        else:
            print(" " * (n-i) + "**" + " " * ((2*i+1) - 2) + "**" )
               
    
    # Lower half of the diamond
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
      
        if i == 0 or i == n - 1:
            print(" " * ((n-i)+1) + "*" * (2*i+1))
        elif i == 1:
            print(" " * ((n-i)+1) + "***" + " " )
        else:
            print(" " * (n-i) + "**" + " " * ((2*i+1) - 2) + "**" + " ")
```

Examples

```
hollow_diamond(7)
print()  # Print a newline for better readability
hollow_diamond(3)
​
        *
       *** 
     **   **
    **     **
   **       **
  **         **
  *
  **         ** 
   **       ** 
    **     ** 
     **   ** 
       *** 
        *

    *
   *** 
  *
   *** 
    *
```

Expected output:

```
>>> hollow_diamond(7)
      *
     ***
    ** **
   **   **
  **     **
 **       **
**         **
 **       **
  **     **
   **   **
    ** **
     ***
      *

>>> hollow_diamond(3)
  *
 ***
** **
 ***
  *
```

Comment: Why the clause `elif i == (n+1):`? If `i` is from `range(n)` then it will never get to `n+1`.

Answer (score 3):

After some reasoning and some trial and error this is what I got:

```py
def hollow_diamond(n):
    # Upper half of the diamond
    for i in range(n):

        if i == 0:  # top of the diamond
            print(" " * ((n-i)) + "*")
        elif i == 1:  # second row of the diamond
            print(" " * ((n-i)) + "***" + " ")
        else:  # rest of the rows of the top part of the diamond
            print(" " * (n-i) + "**" + " " * ((2*i) - 3) + "**")

    # Lower half of the diamond
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):

        if i == 0:  # bottom of the diamond
            print(" " * ((n-i)) + "*")
        elif i == 1:  # second row from the bottom
            print(" " * ((n-i)) + "***" + " ")
        else:  # rest of the rows of the bottom part of the diamond
            print(" " * (n-i) + "**" + " " * ((2*i) - 3) + "**" + " ")


hollow_diamond(7)
print()
hollow_diamond(3)

#        *
#       ***
#      ** **
#     **   **
#    **     **
#   **       **
#  **         **
#   **       **
#    **     **
#     **   **
#      ** **
#       ***
#        *

#    *
#   ***
#  ** **
#   ***
#    *
```

I removed the second part of the condition `if i == 0 or i == n - 1:` in both the upper and lower half, and this was your main problem because `i==n-1` in the upper half means that you are at the center of the diamond, not at the bottom of it. The bottom is `i==0` in the bottom for loop.

I also removed the `if i == n+1` since this was never possibly true.

Furthermore, I adjusted the coefficient in order to obtain a slimmer diamond, which is what you wanted as a solution.

Hope this is helpful!